# Condição IF, ELSE

Tags: java, hibernate, aplicação-web, jpa, spring-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação Java Spring MVC, com Hibernate e JPA e interface HTML.

Tenho Dois formulários que dependem da classe CadernosCadastrados e seus atributos.

Os formulários tem os seguintes nomes, cadastrodecadernos, alterar.

No primeiro formulário que é cadastrocaderno eu insiro os dados de um novo Caderno, detalhe apenas alguns campos como id, numeroCaderno, data, quemDigitou, quemRecebeu e n°Cadernos, apenas isso e mando salvar no banco e é criado um novo ID para esse registro.

Quando faço uma pesquisa, no caso id=1 que foi gerado pelo sistema, é exibido um formulário com os dados do primeiro formulário anterior salvo, estes dados veem preechidos o que faço é apenas acrescentar novos dados neste segundo formulario, preenchendo os novos dados, tem um checkbox neste formulario com os atributos statusPendentes e statusFinalizados aonde escolho Pendente ou Finalizado, feito isso mando salvar é salvo no banco de dados. digamos que optei pelo checkbox statusFinalizados é salvo no banco de dados como statusFinalizados.

Quando eu fizer a pesquisa novamente, no caso id=1 ele vai cair na mesma pagina de alterar, detalhe se eu digitei na pesquisa id=1 ele tem que retornar uma mensagem na tela, "Este caderno está finalizado não pode ser alterado", porque eu registrei no cadastro anterior como statusFinalizado.

Método ID da Classe ControllerCaderno que é chamado quando faço uma pesquisa pelo ID e mostra os resultados do formulario, ambos para statusPendentes ou statusFinalizados, se for finalizado, tem que retornar a mensagem "Este caderno bla bla", no momento está retornando a mensagem para ambos tantos statusPendentes como statusFinalizados.?

```
@GetMapping("id")
public String buscarNumeroID(@Valid CadernosCadastrados objeto, Model model, boolean statusPendentes, boolean statusFinalizados, Long id) {
    List<CadernosCadastrados> cadernos = daoCadernosCadastrados.buscarNumeroID(id); 

        if(cadernos.equals(cadernos) != statusFinalizados) {    

            model.addAttribute("mensagem", "Este caderno está finalizado não 
             pode ser alterado!");

        }

        if(cadernos.equals(cadernos) != statusPendentes) {
         model.addAttribute("cadernos", cadernos); 
         return "public/alterar";

    }


    return "public/sucessos";

}
```

Metodo Dao, do ID, aonde busco os dados do ID salvo no banco de dados.

```
public List<CadernosCadastrados> buscarID(Long  id) {
    TypedQuery<CadernosCadastrados> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT d FROM CadernosCadastrados d WHERE d.id = :id order by id desc", CadernosCadastrados.class);
    query.setParameter("id", id); 
    return query.getResultList();


}
```

Metodo alterar da Classe ControllerCaderno, aonde eu trago a lista e mando salvar os novos registros do formulario anterior.

```
@RequestMapping("alterar")
public String alterar(CadernosCadastrados  objeto, Long id, BindingResult result, Model model, boolean statusPendentes, boolean statusFinalizados) {
    List<CadernosCadastrados> cadernos = daoCadernosCadastrados.buscarNumeroID(id);

      daoCadernosCadastrados.alterar(objeto);

            return "public/sucessos";  

}
```

Método dao Alterar, da classe ControllerCaderno aonde eu salvo os dados do formulario anterior e assim salva os dados no banco dados.

public void alterar(CadernosCadastrados objeto) {

```
    entityManager.merge(objeto);
```

}

Comment: Aqui você busca o caderno pelo número certo? List<CadernosCadastrados> cadernos = daoCadernosCadastrados.buscarNumeroCaderno(numeroCaderno); O objeto CadernosCadastrados então tem dois atributos statusPendente e statusFinalizados?
E daí a depender se um dos dois atributos for nulo retornar páginas diferentes?
Desculpe, não conseguir entender muito bem.

Comment: Então amigo eu coloquei estes atributos porque quando for chamar no banco, ae verifica se é Pendente ou Finalizado. eu criei este atributo normal na classe Caderno com String, a melhor solução é fazer um Enum não é.

Answer (score 0):

Desculpa amigo, não sei se conseguir entender bem o que você precisa e qual a sua dificuldade, mas vamos lá...

Observei algumas coisas estranhas no seu método buscarNumeroCaderno e por isso gostaria de deixar algumas perguntas.

1. Se a intenção é apenas buscar por número do caderno, por que
   está passando como parâmetro CadernosCadastrados, statusPendente,
   statusFinalizado e id? Além disso nenhum desses parâmetros estão
   sendo usados no corpo do método.
2. Pelo que entendi, ao realizar uma pesquisa, o sistema deve
   retornar um formulário com os dados do caderno e a informação se é
   novo, pendente, finalizado ou inexistente. Se o retorno deste método é uma página
   formulário por que
   `daoCadernosCadastrados.buscarNumeroCaderno(numeroCaderno)` retorna
   uma lista de cadernos? Pode ter no banco de dados mais de um caderno
   com o mesmo número? Se isso é possível, onde está o tratamento desse
   possível retorno? Porque não é usual exibir mais de um caderno em um
   formulário. Se isso não é possível, é bom rever a implementação do
   método daoCadernosCadastrados.buscarNumeroCaderno(numeroCaderno) e
   deixar o retorno coerente com a situação.

Depois que você observar essas questões e deixar o código mais claro será possível te auxiliar com mais precisão, mas para fazer o que você precisa acredito que o código abaixo resolve, não é a melhor forma mas já está um passo a mais da versão original:

```
@GetMapping("numeroCaderno")
public String buscarPorNumeroCaderno(Model model, String numeroCaderno) {
    Caderno caderno = daoCadernosCadastrados.buscarNumeroCaderno(numeroCaderno);

    if (caderno != null) {

        model.addAttribute("mensagem", "");
        model.addAttribute("caderno", caderno);

        if (enumStatus.PENDENTE.equals(caderno.status)) {
             return "public/caderno_pendente";
        }

        if (enumStatus.FINALIZADO.equals(caderno.status)) {
             return "public/caderno_finalizado";
        }

        return "public/caderno_novo";  

    }

    return "public/sem_resultados";

}
```

Comment: Olá amigo, então vamos lá, eu tenho um formulário, faço um cadastro e salvo até ae normal, sem problemas quando faço a pesquisa no caso "numeroCaderno" ele retorna a mesma pagina com os dados preenchidos e um checkbox é neste checkbox que eu marco se for "Pendente" e quando fizer a pesquisa ele retorna esta pagina "Pendente" se eu optar por "Finalizado" ele retorna esta mesma pagina mas com o nome de "Finalizado" e se eu fizer uma pesquisa e não encontrar no banco nenhum "Caderno" nem Pendente e nem Finalizado tem que retornar a pagina "sem_resultados".

Comment: Então amigo, segui sua lógica e com isso o retorno está dando "sem_resultados" sendo que eu cadastrei um caderno como "pendente", o certo seria a página pendente  e não sem_resultados.